# Can these formulas be simplified? Why does INDIRECT function seem to not work inside an ISBLANK test within a MATCH formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

## Summary

I need an array formula that takes a row of data of certain length from Sheet1. For that row, in each column that is not blank, I need to grab the Sheet1 header value for that column and display that data in a continuous row on Sheet2 (without any spaces in between the row's cells).

## Background

I have a table of data (employees and industry certifications with expiration date being the table's cell data) on sheet 1, with a row for each employee the spreadsheet is tracking. The certifications are the columns.

We are using this information to link to ID Badge Printer software (Bodno Silver), where we are limited to linking columns of data to a particular textbox.

The problem lies in the fact that not everyone has every certification. The rows are peppered with blanks separating the certifications that each employee does have. While setting up the required text boxes in the badge software template, that each link to a specific column, I quickly realized that since not everyone has every certification if we used the data how it was we would have a bunch of strange looking blanks in between the listed certifications rather than a continuous list.

## What I did

My solution to this (which I'm open to a better one if anyone knows of one, other than "use better software"), was to create a new sheet and array formulas that no one would use except for me and the id printer software. This sheet would have a similar data table that took the rows of data interspersed with blank cells between expiration dates, and put the matching column headers for cells that had a date in them into a continuous row of the same maximum length (eliminating the blank cells).

Essentially, this would allow me to circumvent the restrictions of the badge software and each textbox would be MatchedCert1, MatchedCert2, MatchedCert3, etc. up to the original maximum number of certifications.

Pictures are probably better than my words at explaining what I am going for:

#### Sheet1 (source)

[image: Sheet1]

#### Sheet2 (result)

[image: Sheet2]

## The array formulas

I worked on this one for a while. What I thought would be a simple INDEX, MATCH, ISBLANK formula (that I could create using the appropriate relative and absolute cell linking) and then expand to the whole sheet turned into a witch hunt and me praying for forgiveness for my sins to all that may be holy. Also a lot of googling.... I realized quickly that this one may not be so simple after all.

Finally, I arrived at the following two array formulas in order to correctly show what I was going for:

#### First Column of training section

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$E$2:$P3,1,MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(Sheet1!E3:Q3),0)),"")}
```

(easy enough, right? I thought so...)

I felt good about this until I tried to think through what would be required to get the formula to be universal so that I could use it on the entire table.

I feel dirty just putting the following in public, but here goes...

#### Second column through last column array formula

```
{=IFNA(INDEX(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW($E$2),(MATCH(E3,Sheet1!$2:$2,0)+1),1,1, "Sheet1")&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(E3),COLUMN($Q3),1)),1,MATCH(FALSE, ISBLANK(INDEX(INDIRECT("Sheet1!"&ADDRESS(ROW(E3),(MATCH(E3,Sheet1!$2:$2,0)+1),1)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(E3),COLUMN($Q3),1)),0,0)), 0)),"")}
```

(please don't call the police...)

[ninja edit] While this array formula works for 2nd result column through the final column, it doesn't work if there's not a blank column following the result range. The actual spreadsheet has 4 different groups of certifications that run horizontally, but I was able to just add a blank column in the corresponding data from the other sheet easily enough, so I just let it go. I'd give somebody a nickle for the answer to why that's the case here too [/edit]

## Results

The first array formula, and INDEX MATCH using ISBLANK is rather straightforward.

The biggest question for me here, and the thing that drove me absolutely nuts for a couple of days, is why the second array formula requires the additional INDEX function nested inside of the ISBLANK function.

**While taking the function apart and experimenting I realized that if I have any INDIRECT reference inside a ISBLANK function, which is itself inside of a MATCH function, the result of the match was *ALWAYS* 1:**

```
{=MATCH(FALSE,ISBLANK(INDIRECT("$E3:$Q3")), 0)}
```

**The above *ALWAYS* returns 1, whereas if I put the range in explicitly, the function would work just fine**. That wasn't an option for me, since I needed to dynamically return the starting position for the match using the previous cell's address.

**However, adding an INDEX function (with a column and row value of 0) to encapsulate the INDIRECT function provides the correct answer. I figured this out just by trial and error.**

## Questions

**Can someone with more knowledge please let me know what is causing this behavior?**

**As a broader question, given I am limited to using formulas (no VBA), I would also like to know if I'm going about this in the wrong way or if there is a much simpler way of accomplishing this without this behemoth of a formula?**

I know this sheet will probably require maintenance in a year - good luck future self!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this in E3, Copy over and down

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$2:$2,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN(INDEX($E:$P,MATCH($C3,Sheet1!$C:$C,0),0))/(INDEX(Sheet1!$E:$P,MATCH($C3,Sheet1!$C:$C,0),0)<>""),COLUMN(A:A))),"")
```

As to why your formula is not working, it is too convoluted to parse.  One note, unless the sheets is the variable, one should avoid INDIRECT as much as possible.  INDEX can almost always be used in its place.

Both INDIRECT and ADDRESS are volatile functions.  Volatile functions will re-calculate every time Excel re-calculates, leading to a lot of unnecessary computations.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I'm attempting to decipher this right now and it could very well be my solution, but as of right now it's not working (fills all cells with 0's) in the test workbook I created for the question or a copy of the original workbook. If I can get it to work I'll come back and mark it.

Comment: Thank you very much. That definitely works.

As to your answer that it's too convoluted, I would buy that except I don't see how turning 
[1] MATCH(FALSE, ISBLANK(INDIRECT(...)),0) 
into
[2] MATCH(FALSE, ISBLANK(INDEX(INDIRECT(...),0,0)), 0) 
simplifies the calculation?

I feel like I'm missing something about the return type of INDIRECT, like maybe it doesn't return an actual reference but a instance of the reference? I'm not sure. Thank you all the same, since this is the approach I need to learn anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution but to answer why you are seeing this behavior:

EDIT: PREVIOUS EXPLANATION WAS JUST PLAIN WRONG

This confused me so, I did a bit of investigation:

[image]

I think that your problem is actually coming from the ISBLANK function because it is intended to be used with single values, and cannot handle ranges. Any BLANKs which are returned by functions are only converted to numeric values (0), when the BLANK is returned to (or displayed on) the sheet. If the function is returning to another function, the BLANK value seems to be preserved.

EDIT: ADDING A SOLUTION WITHOUT ARRAY FORMULAS

This is probably more complex than using an array formula... but I strongly dislike them, so do all I can to remove them.

Firstly, I would add an index to your positions in the results sheet:

[image]

```
=IF(F$7>COUNTIFS($F3:$L3,"<>"),
    "",
    IF(
        MINIFS(
            $F$7:$L$7,$F$7:$L$7,
            ">" & IFNA(INDEX($F$7:$L$7,MATCH(E9,$F$2:$L$2,0)),0),
            $F3:$L3,
            "<>"
        )=0,
        "",
        INDEX(
            $F$2:$L$2,
            MATCH(
                MINIFS(
                    $F$7:$L$7,$F$7:$L$7,
                    ">" & IFNA(INDEX($F$7:$L$7,MATCH(E9,$F$2:$L$2,0)),0),
                    $F3:$L3,
                    "<>"
                ),
                $F$7:$L$7,
                0
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Basically, the formula looks at the cert in the previous cell, and looks for the next, minimum index, greater than that.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. I really was looking to learn why indirect was not working as inspected. The only remaining question I have then, is why did wrapping the indirect function inside a INDEX(INDIRECT(...),0) function cause the formula to begin working.

I also have learned from your response that creating a large vertical formula space and providing appropriate tabbing for the formulas helps immensely with readability, I will have to also look in to the MINIFS function. I appreciate your response immensely, thank you again.

Comment: Turns out that it seems my original explanation was incorrect. I have done a bit more digging. Please see my revised answer.

Comment: I very much appreciate your revised explanation that actually answers the part of the question I had regarding the MATCH(FALSE, ISBLANK(INDIRECT(<range written as string>)), 0) vs MATCH(FALSE, ISBLANK(INDEX(INDIRECT(<range written as string>),0,0)), 0).

I also appreciate you providing me with an alternative to the other solution presented, and a new way to look at going about editing formulas in the future. However, I do prefer the other solution to the problem that was presented, and I would also point out that the other solution works as a normal (non-array) formula.